# SEO impact: personalization by redirecting user to a different page

Tags: seo, redirects

I want to integrate personalization on some e-commerce website.

This website has two product categories:

- shoes for men
- shoes for women

In visit 1, an user types in `www.example.com` and arrives on a generic landing page showing shoes for men and women. Then, the user visits pages with shoes for women. This information is stored in a cookie.

In visit 2, the same user types in `www.example.com`, the browser reads the cookie and redirects the user to a personalized landing page showing shoes for women with an url, such as `www.example.com/women-lp`.

Is such a redirect bad for SEO?

Answer (score 1):

Most bots don't accept cookies so Google wouldn't know that the user was being redirected.  The key for SEO would be how does Google know about the shoes for men and women pages.  Since you apparently have links from the main page to these, Google should find them fine and the cookies is nothing more than a personalizing feature, like a shopping cart.

[What happens if I try to set a cookie on a bot?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59652/what-happens-if-i-try-to-set-a-cookie-on-a-bot)

Answer (score 1):

Despite the fact Googlebot is a browser it doesn't eat cookies. So it is not a problem.

Similar action schema Google recommends by its own to establish a user friendly multilanguage site:

`first visit → select language → set cookie → next visit → redirect to certain language version according to language setting saved in cookie`.

It is very important, that you redirect your visitors based only on cookie: not on browser language, not on ip addresse, not on user agent.

And, surely, shoes for man and women should be both indexed.